# Uncompress in .NET Compact Framework 1.0

Tags: c#, compact-framework, compression

I need a library I can use to uncompress a collection of files (something similar to unzipping). Any compression format will do. So far I have failed to find any zip libraries that meet my requirements. The library needs to meet the following requirements:

1) .NET Compact Framework 1.0 compatible.

2) I need access to the code (must be C#) so I can include it in my project. I can't use a dll file.

3) Preferably all managed code.

Comment: Isn't .NET CF2 five years out now?  Are you really still using the predecessor for new development?

Comment: Yes, as part of an installation process that among other things unzips some files and installs version 3.5 of .NET CF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/download.aspx

Open source and works with .NET CF 1 and 2.

EDIT:

There are conditional compilation constants you can set to specify the Framework, e.g.:

```
#elif (NETCF_1_0)
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("SharpZipLib for .NET Compact Framework 1.0")]
#elif (NETCF_2_0)
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("SharpZipLib for .NET Compact Framework 2.0")]
```

From checking the #ziplib source it seems that the only limitation for .NET CF 1.0 is that you cannot encrypt or decrypt files within a .zip archive (Cf 1.0 doesn't supply `System.Security.Cryptography`).

Comment: Actually even though they say it works with CF1 it does not. They say they provide CF1 binaries, but they do not. The code does not compile for CF1.

Comment: IIRC, you need to set a conditional compilation constant (NETCF_1_0) in your project and rebuild the SharpZipLib code from scratch. This should remove all the references to things like CultureInfo that CF doesn't support.

Comment: I noticed that too and I set the NETCF_1_0 compilation constant, but it still does not build. Did you get this to build?

Comment: I removed and re-added all the cs files and the compilation symbol and for some reason it builds now. I will mark you answer as correct after I verify that this will really run on CF1 and I can really unzip files with it. Thanks.